# Django - dictionary passed in redirect is not showing in template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to redirect my signup form to the same form after saving the values also I wanted to return a dictionary in the redirect response. 
But the following code is not working.

urls.py

```
url(r'^signupform/$', views.render_signup, name='render_signup'),
url(r'^signup/$', views.sign_up_account_admin, name='sign_up_account_admin'),
```

views.py

```
def render_signup(request):
    """
    """
    data_dict = {"some_keys":"some_values"}
    return render(request, "admin.html", data_dict)



def sign_up_account_admin(request):
    """
    """
    user = None
    user, msg = save_form_data(request)
    req_dict = {"msg": msg}
    if user:
        ret = redirect('homepage') #-- This works pretty fine
    else:
        ret = redirect('/signupform/', resp = req_dict) #-- This redirects but I don't get the `resp` Objects in the template
    return ret
```

Html Temlpate

```
    <div class="container">
      =={{resp}}
      ===>>>>>>>{{resp.msg}}
    </div>
```

And the Output HTML

```
  <div class="container">
      ==
      ===>>>>>>>
   </div>
```

Comment: `redirect()` doesn't pass its parameters to the template. It's like you make new request to specified url. You can pass data in the query parameters or session if you need.

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin - I thought, as we were able to do that using `HttpResponseredirect` by passing kwargs in `reverse` method. Do we have such any other option here?

Comment: Yes, if you have url defined as `/some-url/{id}/`, than passing `kwargs` to `reverse` will fill `{id}` part. Those are completely different things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can't pass random `kwargs` to the [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) function.**

The arguments passed to `redirect` are the same positional or keyword arguments which you would have passed had you used `reverse()` to generate the url. These arguments are used to reverse resolve the url.

As mentioned in the Django docs about using [`redirect()` function.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#examples)

> By passing the name of a view and optionally some positional or
>   keyword arguments; the URL will be reverse resolved using the
>   [`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse) method.

**Now, as you are passing a hardcoded url, then the argument passed along with it will get discarded.**

The recommended way to use `redirect()` with a hardcoded url as mentioned in Django docs is:

```
def my_view(request):
    ...
    return redirect('/some/url/')
```

So, what you can do now is use to Django sessions or maybe pass a parameter in the url to access the value of `resp` in the `render_signup` view.

**Solution-1 Using Django Sessions**

One way is to use Django sessions to get the `msg`.

```
def sign_up_account_admin(request):
    """
    """
    user = None
    user, msg = save_form_data(request)
    req_dict = {"msg": msg}
    if user:
        ret = redirect('homepage') #-- This works pretty fine
    else:
        request.session['resp'] = msg # set in session
        ret = redirect('/signupform/')

    return ret
```

Then in your `render_signup` view, you can do:

```
def render_signup(request):
    """
    """
    resp = request.session.get('resp') # get the value from session
    data_dict = {'resp': resp, ..}
    return render(request, "admin.html", data_dict)
```

**Solution-2 Pass it as url parameters**

Another solution is to pass it in url as query parameters.

```
ret = redirect('/signupform/?resp=%s'%msg) # pass as query parameter
```

Then in the `render_signup` view, get this value from `request.GET`.

```
resp = request.GET.get('resp') # get the value of 'resp' from request.GET
data_dict = {'resp':resp, ..}
```

**EDIT:**

If you have multiple parameters to send which are in a dictionary, then you can use [`urllib.urlencode()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) to encode the dictionary and send it with the url.

```
encoded_string = urllib.urlencode(my_dict)
redirect('/signupform/?%s'%encoded_string) # attach the encoded string in the url
```

Then in your view, you can retrieve the keys of the dictionary from `request.GET`.

```
value1 = request.GET.get('key1')
value2 = request.GET.get('key2')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have a quite bigger dictionary to return so not good idea to store big dictionary in the session. So I would go with some other solution. :(

Comment: You can encode the dictionary to `percent-encoded` string and pass it along with the url. Updated the ans.

Comment: In python 3 the urllib library has changed, the documentation is here (for Solution-2): https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode